# What programming languages used to create terminal apps?

Tags: macos, terminal, homebrew

What are the languages that used to build apps like:
ls, curl, nmap, htop
and other homebrew apps like: youtube-dl.

I'm wonder about; if I want to build an app to run it through terminal and published in homebrew, what language should I used?

Comment: You can use any language; Homebrew doesn’t select software based on the language it’s written in (as long as there’s a way to compile/interpret it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- ls - C
- curl - C
- nmap - C++
- htop - C
- youtube-dl - Python
- Homebrew itself - Ruby

Almost every language that works on OS X can be used to develop a command-line program.

A user that has Homebrew installed on OS X already has support for C, C++, Objective-C, Swift, Python, Ruby, Perl, and Tcl, so I would suggest using one of those languages. You could also use Bash (version 3.2.57 as of OS X 10.11.4) or awk or AppleScript and I may have forgotten some others.